# Divide value depending on the condition of the column in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I would like to divide the value of a column according to a condition.

Something like the following:

```
Data$ColumnA [Data$ColumnA>50 && Data$ColumnB> 0] <- Data$ColumnA / 25
```

The problem is `Data$ColumnA / 25` loses the "index", and makes the division of the first value in the list.

Thank you

Comment: You have to apply the index to both sides, otherwise they are different lengths.  Also, use `&` not `&&` as you want a vector of logical values as your index.  So `idx <- (Data$ColumnA>50 & Data$ColumnB>0)` then `Data$ColumnA[idx] <- Data$ColumnA[idx] / 25`

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please always provide a complete reproducible example to make it easier for us to answer. In your question it would be helpful to add some example data as R code and show the expected result for the example data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using a `data.table` instead of a `data.frame` not only for performance reasons but also because the syntax is more compact:

```
library(data.table)

Data <- data.frame(ColumnA = seq(0, 175, by = 25),
                   ColumnB = c(0, 1))
Data
# ColumnA ColumnB
# 1       0       0
# 2      25       1
# 3      50       0
# 4      75       1
# 5     100       0
# 6     125       1
# 7     150       0
# 8     175       1

setDT(Data)  # "convert" data.frame into a data.table

Data[ColumnA > 50 & ColumnB > 0, ColumnA := ColumnA / 25]

Data
# ColumnA ColumnB
# 1:       0       0
# 2:      25       1
# 3:      50       0
# 4:       3       1
# 5:     100       0
# 6:       5       1
# 7:     150       0
# 8:       7       1
```